# CakePHP: How to switch two row values from a unique field?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I need to change the value of two rows in the `order` field of my database. This field is unique.

**What I tried:**

1. Storing the value of **both items** in a PHP variable,
2. Setting the **first row**'s field value to `NULL` (nulls are accepted in the field),
3. Setting the value of the **second row**'s field to the value that was held on the first row,
4. Setting the **first row**'s field value to the original second row field value.

---

It doesn't work, since I am getting a "dupplicate entry" error when executing the order change. I can't seem to find out how to do this using CakePHP.

Here is the code that I have written (even though it's not functionnal):

```
if ($second_row) {
    $next = $second_row['Immeuble']['order'];
    $prev = $first_row['Immeuble']['order'];

    $this->Immeuble->id = $first_row_id;
    $this->Immeuble->saveField('order', 'null');


    $this->Immeuble->id = $second_row['Immeuble']['id'];
    $this->Immeuble->saveField('order', $prev);

    $this->Immeuble->id = $first_row_id;
    $this->Immeuble->saveField('order',$next);
}
```

Comment: double check that `$first_row_id` and `$second_row['Immeuble]'['id']` are infact the correct values. Also, it might be a non-issue but if `order` is an `int` datatype, you should: `saveField('order', null)` to save it as `NULL` - otherwise it gets treated as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I stated above **is fully functionnal**. I just had **inverted** some values, which would screw everything up. I will not delete the question in case someone else needs to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

of course its dublicate key

you defined id two times

```
     $this->Immeuble->id = $first_row_id;
```

and

```
     $this->Immeuble->id = $second_row['Immeuble']['id'];
```

and then

```
     $this->Immeuble->id = $first_row_id;
```

try remove this last line

Comment: But by doing this, the selected `id` in my model will still be the one of the second row, and I dont want the first row to remain null, I want it to take the value of the second row. The first row goes `NULL`, then has to be set to that the second row had at the beginning. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: why cant u use if statment when first_row is NULL  then do it equal the second_row